# Vector fields - Chapter 0, Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

There's the following observation with a very short proof:

> Observe that if $\varphi : M \to M$ is a diffeomorphism, $v \in T_p M$ and $f$ is a differentiable function in a neighborhood of $\varphi(p)$ , we have
>   $$
> (d\varphi(p) f) \varphi (p) = v(f \circ \varphi)(p)
> $$
>   Indeed, let $\alpha : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ be a differentiable curve with $\alpha'(0) = v$ and $\alpha(0) = p$. Then
>   $$
> (d \varphi (v) f) \varphi (p) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} (f \circ \varphi \circ \alpha) \right|_{t=0} = v(f \circ \varphi)(p)
> $$

I don't get the very last line, I suppose it follows from the definition given of tangent vector, but I really can't work out the details.

Could you explain more in detail that line?

Thank you (P.S. here $M$ is a differentiable manifold).

**Update** : In the statement of [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156686/chapter-0-proposition-2-7-do-carmo-reimannian-geometry-bit-of-confusing-notati?rq=1) $\beta$ is defined as $\beta = \varphi \circ \alpha$. Given a curve $\alpha : (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to M$ (differentiable manifold) a tangent vector is defined as

$$
\alpha'(0) f = \frac{d}{dt} (f \circ \alpha).
$$

Using $\beta$ instead of $\alpha$ we have

$$
\beta'(0)f = \frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \beta) = \frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \varphi \circ \alpha)
$$

but $\beta'(0) = d \varphi_p(v)$ therefore $\beta'(0) f = d \varphi_p(v) f$ and therefore we have

$$
d \varphi_p(v) f = \frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \varphi \circ \alpha)
$$

Therefore what I think I'm actually missing is the meaning of the notation $ \left( d \varphi_p(v) f \right) \varphi(p)$

**More details**

Just to clarify, my previous update is my interpretation of the notation used, I've noticed there's some inconsistencies (I think) in the notation used throughout the book (at least for chapter 0).

1) In definition 2.6.

The author defines a tangent vector to a differentiable manifold $M$ as an operator $\alpha'(0) : \cal{D} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\cal{D}$ is the set of differentiable functions defined on $M$. Such description makes very clear to me the meaning of the notation $\alpha'(0)f$, If I view it as an operator. Moreover we have the expression given

$$
\alpha'(0) f = \frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \alpha)
$$

The right handside of the expression in terms of computation is clear to me, because of the parameterization.

2) In proposition 2.7, given a differentiable map $\varphi$ between two differentiable manifolds $M_1^n, M_2^m$ and the differential $d \varphi_p(v)$ is defined. To define this differential we need a $p \in M_1^n$ and a tangent vector $v \in T_p M_1^n$. The differential is a map from $T_p M_1^n$ to $T_{\varphi(p)} M_2^m$, and therefore it acts as an operator from the set of differentiable functions on $M_2^m$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Thefore the meaning of the notation $ d \varphi_p(v) f $ is still clear to me.

3) My original question concern page 26 of the book, where the notation $(d \varphi(v) f)\varphi(p)$ is introduced. The reason I get confused is in the first place I think there's a mistake in the notation used because if you compare $d \varphi_p(v) f$ against $(d \varphi (v) f) \varphi(p)$ there's some difference. I don't know for example what $d \varphi(v)$ means, but I do know what $d \varphi_p(v)$ means. Also $d \varphi_p(v) f$ returns a real value by definition and this doesn't not seem evident to me from $(d \varphi(v) f) \varphi(p)$.

I hope I clarified what my issue is.

Comment: How I interpret this is that you have a derivation at $\varphi(p)$ on the LHS and at $p$ on the RHS.  Basically, repeating what you probably know, $v$ takes in a $C^{\infty}$ function at $p$ and spits out a number (i.e. the RHS) so $d \varphi (v) \in T_{\varphi (p)}(M)$ takes a $C^{\infty}$ function at $\varphi(p)$ and spits out a real number (the LHS).

Comment: I'll write an update where I'll expound a bit more the details of my question.

Comment: Hope it is better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the notation (though it is clumsily written) is that of taking the derivative of $f$ at the value $\varphi(p)$ with respect to the vector $d\varphi_p(v)$ since in this case $v\in T_pM$ and therefore $d\varphi_p(v)\in T_{\varphi(p)}M$.  A much clearer way to convey the same idea would be to write $\left. \left (d\varphi_p(v)f\right ) \right |_{\varphi(p)}$.

I've worked through a lot of do Carmo, and I can comfortably say as a fair warning that his notations are less clear than other treatments of manifold theory and Riemannian geometry.  In my experience, do Carmo's chapter 0 is a poor place to learn the subject for the first time.  I'd highly recommend comparing his text to analogous statements in other books.  For example, consider using John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* as a companion text.  It might be easier to come back to do Carmo and learn Riemannian geometry there after learning about manifolds elsewhere.

Comment: Did you notice he missed the subscript  p in the differential?

Comment: @Mnifldz Please, could you clarify the meaning of $(d\varphi_p(v) f)|_{\varphi(p)}$? For me it does not make sense, since $d\varphi_p(v) f$ is a real number. Do you mean the directional derivative of $f$ at $\varphi(p)$ along the direction $d\varphi_p(v)$?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I don't think it makes sense to think of the quantity $d\varphi_p(v)f$ by itself.  $v$ is a vector field, $d\varphi(v)$ is the pushforward of $v$, $d\varphi_p(v_p) \in T_{\varphi(p)}M$ is the pushforward of the vector $v_p \in T_pM$, and $d\varphi(v)f$ is the derivation of the function $f$ with respect to the pushforward vector field.  When we evaluate this at a point however, we need to recognize that $v$ is pushed from point $p$ to $\varphi(p)$ and the evaluation occurs at $\varphi(p)$, hence $(d\varphi_p(v))f|_{\varphi(p)}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I apologize, for I am not familiar with pushforwards and derivations. I am just working with this definition by the same book: Let $\alpha:(- \varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to M$ be a curve such that $\alpha(0) = p$. The tangent vector along $\alpha$ at $t = 0$ is the function $\alpha'(0): \mathcal{D} \to \Bbb{R}$ given by
$$
\alpha'(0) f = \frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \alpha)\vert_{t = 0}.
$$

This says that for a vector $v \in T_pM$, $v f \in \Bbb{R}$ for each $f \in \mathcal{D}$. Right?

Here, $\mathcal{D}$ denotes the set of differentiable functions on $M$.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Yes, that is correct.  The main distinction to make though is that in the definition you presented $v$ is a single tangent vector and so produces a single number.  However if $v$ is a *vector field* then for each $p \in M, \; v_pf(p)$ is a real number, hence composed a single object $vf$ is actually another smooth function.

Comment: I see, but isn't $d \varphi_p(v)$ a tangent *vector*, thus making sense to think of $d \varphi_p(v) f$ as a real number? I am failing to see this as a vector field.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I think this comes back to my main comment about do Carmo that I said above.  **His notations are confusing.**  If you declare $v$ as a tangent *vector* at the beginning of the problem then you're correct.  But if you declare $v$ as a vector *field*, then the answer is no.  It's more clear to just declare fields as $X \in \mathcal{X}(M)$ and then talk about individual vectors by using subscripts $X_p \in T_pM$.

Comment: I think now I get it. Many thanks for your time and for the help.

Answer (score 0):

${d\over {dt}}(f\circ \varphi\circ \alpha)_{t=0}$ is the differential of the composition of $f\circ\varphi$ and $\alpha$. We thus have:

${d\over {dt}}(f\circ \varphi\circ \alpha)_{t=0}$

$d(f\circ\varphi)_{\alpha(0)})\circ {d\over {dt}}\alpha_{t=0}$

=$d(f\circ\varphi)_{p})(v)=v(f\circ\varphi)(p)$.

Comment: That's not the bit I'm missing, I'm missing the first half of the equalities chain.

Comment: To clarify... why is $$(d \varphi (v) f) \varphi (p) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} (f \circ \varphi \circ \alpha) \right|_{t=0} $$?

Comment: There's an issue with your use of the parenthesis.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details of what is unclear to me, the chain rule you're using in your derivation is not proved in this chapter, but a similar rule is proved in his other book differential geometry of curves and surfaces.